# ninject and enterprise library service locator dependant assemblies

Tags: c#, ninject, enterprise-library

I am using the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation assembly in conjunction with ninject to aid in service loaction. I register my ninject kernel into the servicelocator provider method:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
//do bindings
var locator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
```

The above code all works fine on machines that have the enterprise library installed (via the msi executable). I am not in a position to run the installer in production, so i have the dll locally in the bin directory, hoping this will work. However it does not work. I dont get any assembly not found exceptions, instead i get an object reference not set exception from call to: 'at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.get_Current()'.

I have read in a few places that this assembly doesn't have any dependencies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664422%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx and a local dll should do the trick, but it doesnt seem to.

I've tested on a few boxes and the error occurs consistently until i run the installer. Interestingly, after i uninstall the library, it still works (i guess it's cached somewhere).

Has anyone got any experience with type of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue turned out to be that the servicelocator.current was empty because one of the binding modules i was auto registering was missing a dll. because the bootstrapper was being called from the global.asax i had error handling that was *supposed* to be logging any exceptions and continuing (wouldnt want the whole site to stop for this one page). so i never got the reg error and my bootstrapper was failing without telling me.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
//do bindings -> throw error here without reaching below two lines to regiester the service locator
var locator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
```